# Can I apply a browserify "transform" to a single module in my project?

Tags: node.js, browserify

I've got a Node.js project in which I'm using Browserify to package my code for the browser. One of my dependencies (call it "x") uses `const` in its source code, which I'd like to replace using https://github.com/thlorenz/varify. This works fine if I do `browserify -g varify` to apply a global transform. But I'm wondering whether I can target the transform so it only applies to "x" Is this possible?

Comment: Also wondering the same, did you find the answer to this?